# clang-format to format function declaration by macros

Tags: c, clang-format

I have a set of files in which functions are defined using macros. A simplified version is as follows:

```c
#define DECL_GPO(prefix, name, port, pin, def) \
    static inline void prefix##_Set_##name (uint32_t v) \
    { \
        if(0!=v) { \
            GPIO##port->DR_SET = (1 << pin); \
        } else { \
            GPIO##port->DR_CLEAR = (1 << pin); \
        } \
    }

#define DECL_DigOut(name, port, pin, def)   DECL_GPO(DigOut, name, port, pin, def)

/* intentionally badly formatted */
DECL_DigOut(LED0, 4, 23, 0)      DECL_DigOut(LED1, 4, 25, 0)
DECL_DigOut(MAIN_HW0, 3, 14, 0)
        DECL_DigOut(MAIN_HW1, 3, 15, 0)
   DECL_DigOut(MAIN_HW2, 3, 16, 0)
```

my `.clang-format` is [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/reufkz184mbn1nn/.clang-format?dl=0)

Trying to format the file above I get:

```c
#define DECL_GPO(prefix, name, port, pin, def)                                                                         \
    static inline void prefix##_Set_##name(uint32_t v)                                                                 \
    {                                                                                                                  \
        if (0 != v)                                                                                                    \
        {                                                                                                              \
            GPIO##port->DR_SET = (1 << pin);                                                                           \
        }                                                                                                              \
        else                                                                                                           \
        {                                                                                                              \
            GPIO##port->DR_CLEAR = (1 << pin);                                                                         \
        }                                                                                                              \
    }

#define DECL_DigOut(name, port, pin, def) DECL_GPO(DigOut, name, port, pin, def)

DECL_DigOut(LED0, 4, 23, 0) DECL_DigOut(LED1, 4, 25, 0) DECL_DigOut(MAIN_HW0, 3, 14, 0) DECL_DigOut(MAIN_HW1, 3, 15, 0)
    DECL_DigOut(MAIN_HW2, 3, 16, 0)
```

I, however, would like the list of function declarations `DECL_DigOut` to be one per line.

How can I achieve such behavior with clang-format?

Comment: Can't you just add a `;` after your declarations? Should solve the formatting and make it look slightly less weird (in my opinion).

Comment: @Mat you are right. Do you know how I can force to add `;` to the end of declarations?